# Get pid of a browser launched with Playwright

Tags: node.js, playwright

How can I get the pid of a browser launched with Playwright ?
I tried : `browser.process().pid` but it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Curious to know how you're planning on using the pid? We could expose a nicer API in Playwright if it's a common use-case

Comment: I'm not OP, but I'm using the pid to kill the associated TCP sessions, in order to test client behavior on network failures.

Comment: @arjunattam Imagine multiple scripts all using playwright launching chromium + playwright.sh (windows) and an issue sometimes occurs with atleast selenium where the process gets stuck even after script quitting fully keeping browser window open. Thats why I usually kill all processes named chromium and playwright.sh. Now if there are multiple scripts running I cannot do that and if the scripts keep leaving zombie processes behind then eventually all memory will be used for such processes. That is why it would be great if there is a method returning pid(s) of started processes by playwright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot apply `process()` on `browser` context but only on `browserServer`,** which requires a `launchServer()` first place (and not regular `launch()`). see the docs about [browserServer.process()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browserserver#browser-server-process).

**You will need to launch the server like this to get an instance with a valid `pid`:**

```js
  const browserServer = await playwright.chromium.launchServer()
  const pid = await browserServer.process().pid
  console.log(pid)
```