# Get pid of a browser launched with Playwright in JAVA Version

Tags: java, playwright

how to get pid of a browser launched with Playwright in JAVA Version

there is an answer in node.js:
[Get pid of a browser launched with Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376437/get-pid-of-a-browser-launched-with-playwright)

but I can't find the solution of java version.
is there some one can help me with that?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the browser server is not exposed in java. You can go and expose your use-case in the java repo! https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-java